# How to select a value from a DataFrame (even if there is no entry)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to select an entry from a DataFrame structure based on some conditions. It works - as long as there is an entry that fits to the query (first example in code shown below)

But sometimes, there is no proper entry, so the return value should be an empty string (not an error message). This I cannot achieve.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

data = {'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2],
        'Key': ['Key1','Key2','Key1','Key2'],
        'Value': ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4']
        }

df = DataFrame(data,columns= ['ID', 'Key','Value'])

print(df.loc[(df['ID']==1) & (df['Key'] == 'Key2')].iloc[-1,-1])
# shows "Value2" (correct)

print(df.loc[(df['ID']==1) & (df['Key'] == 'Key3')].iloc[-1,-1])
# should show "" (desired output)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to index in to an empty dataframe, which you can't do. You can catch the exception and have it print a string if you want, but there's no way around the IndexError itself when doing what you're trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does what you are looking for:

```
keyname = 'Key2' # Key3
try:
    print(df.loc[(df['ID']==1) & (df['Key'] == keyname)].iloc[-1,-1])
except IndexError:
    print("")
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying this a bit more explicitly using a mask that you can inspect.

```
mask = (df['ID']==1) & (df['Key'] == 'Key3')
if mask.any():
    print(df[mask].Value.iloc[0])
else:
    print("")
```

Comment: It won't hide any inadvertent index errors but the other solution is also great